# SQL code to remove extra spaces and line breaks in free text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I'm currently working with a table that deals with patients who have visited a clinic. One of the fields in this table shows the reason for the visit, and it's free text so whoever's booking the appointment can leave a custom note for the doctor depending on what the issue is. Yes, I'm well aware free text is the actual worst, but I did not design this database or the front-end medical record system (which is also the worst) and I'm simply stuck dealing with it. Bear with me.

Because of the special characters, extra spaces, and carriage returns that often find their way into that free text field on the front end, all its contents would show up on a single line in SSMS but would cause all sorts of formatting issues with extra line breaks when the SQL results were pasted into Excel. I did a little research and found a snippet of code that would replace carriage returns, etc. in a given field, thus forcing all the contents of that field to remain in a single cell:

`REPLACE(REPLACE(FieldName,char(10),''),char(13),'') as FieldName`

This has worked splendidly for this `VisitReason` field and any other free text fields I've been forced to work with. *However*, does it account for every possible issue one might find in free text? Yesterday I was working with this table and pasted the results from SSMS into Excel, and there were two people whose `VisitReason` fields were cut off prematurely and then had *all* the results (as in multiple fields) from a bunch of other people's visits crammed into that same field (thus making for one really long cell in Excel).

For example, the `VisitReason` for one of these people showed up in SSMS as `complaining of rash, see note`. But then when it was pasted into Excel, the results looked like...

```
PatientID    PatientName    VisitDate   ...   VisitReason
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001         Smith, John    01/08/2023  ...   complaining of rash, see
                                              PatientID1002PatientNameJaneDoeVisitDate01/08/2023VisitRe
                                              asondiabetesfollowupPatientID1003PatientNameBobBrownVisitDa
                                              (and so on)
```

I can't tell if this has something to do with the free text field, and there's some hidden character in there that's causing the weird line breaks and field merging that my `REPLACE` function isn't catching, or whether it's an error with Excel (in which case this obviously isn't the right place to be asking). But I wanted to check and see if there was anything that potentially needed to be added to the `REPLACE` line that would fix the problem.

My full query is really simple:

```
SELECT
    d.PatientID,
    d.PatientName,
    v.VisitDate,
    [some other visit-related fields, none of which are free text],
    REPLACE(REPLACE(v.VisitReason,char(10),''),char(13),'') as VisitReason,
    [some other demographic fields, none of which are free text]

FROM Demographics d 
JOIN Visit v ON d.PatientID = v.PatientID
```

The `REPLACE` function works perfectly fine for literally every other patient in the list except for the two with results like what's shown above, which then go on to affect a number of other rows following them. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: `"... when pasted into Excel"` Honestly, I would exclude this field, or include only the first 40 or so characters, when running queries where Excel is the expected destination. But also, I'd look to see if I could do this in the client code, rather than the SQL itself.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the only issue is that most of the time when I'm creating these visit reports, whoever asked for them typically wants to see that `VisitReason` field specifically. I leave that field out when I can, but most of the time it's unavoidable.

Comment: They have a choice: either they see the field, or they use Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

The `xs:token` data type is stripping out the white space characters.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.udf_tokenize;
GO

/*
1. All invisible TAB, Carriage Return, and Line Feed characters will be replaced with spaces.
2. Then leading and trailing spaces are removed from the value. 
3. Further, contiguous occurrences of more than one space will be replaced with a single space.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_tokenize(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
   RETURN (SELECT CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @input + ' ' + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)'));
END
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @mockTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), col_1 VARCHAR(100), col_2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockTbl (col_1, col_2) VALUES 
(CHAR(13) + '  FL   ' + CHAR(9), CHAR(10) + '  Miami'),
('  FL   ', '  Fort       Lauderdale   '),
('  NY   ', '  New           York   '),
('  NY   ', ''),
('  NY   ', NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT *, LEN(col_2) AS [col_2_len] 
FROM @mockTbl;

-- remove invisible white space chars
UPDATE @mockTbl
SET col_1 = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_1)
, col_2 = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_2);

-- after
SELECT *, LEN(col_2) AS [col_2_len] 
FROM @mockTbl;
```